# Sorting audio files by duration

Tags: javascript, html

I am storing audio files. When I list them they have a preview player next to them. It looks like this:

[image]

I'm trying to add different sorting types. Here is the *sort-by-name* function:

```
function sortTableByName() {
  var table, rows, switching, i, x, y, shouldSwitch;
  table = document.getElementById("table-design");
  switching = true;
  /*Make a loop that will continue until no switching has been done:*/
  while (switching) {
    //start by saying: no switching is done:
    switching = false;
    rows = table.getElementsByTagName("TR");
    /*Loop through all table rows (except the first, which contains table headers):*/
    for (i = 1; i < (rows.length - 1); i++) {
      //start by saying there should be no switching:
      shouldSwitch = false;
      /*Get the two elements you want to compare, one from current row and one from the next:*/
      x = rows[i].getElementsByTagName("TD")[0];
      y = rows[i + 1].getElementsByTagName("TD")[0];
      //check if the two rows should switch place:
      if (x.innerHTML.toLowerCase() > y.innerHTML.toLowerCase()) {
        //if so, mark as a switch and break the loop:
        shouldSwitch = true;
        break;
      }
    }
    if (shouldSwitch) {
      /*If a switch has been marked, make the switch and mark that a switch has been done:*/
      rows[i].parentNode.insertBefore(rows[i + 1], rows[i]);
      switching = true;
    }
  }
}
```

This worked. Then I tried *sorting by the duration* of the audio.
And here comes the part that confuses me. *Sort-by-name* is simple because it gets the names stored in the first column, so there's only that value there:

```
x = rows[i].getElementsByTagName("TD")[0];
y = rows[i + 1].getElementsByTagName("TD")[0];
//check if the two rows should switch place:
if (x.innerHTML.toLowerCase() > y.innerHTML.toLowerCase()) {
  //if so, mark as a switch and break the loop:
  shouldSwitch = true;
  break;
}
```

**But in the *sort-by-duration* case, the second column doesn't contain only a value, it contains an audio player, can someone tell me how to refer to those players so I can get their duration?**

Below is the HTML for the table:

```
<table id="table-design">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>File browser
        <select id="list">
          <option value="" disabled selected>Sort by</option>
          <option value="1">Name(asc.)</option>
          <option value="2">Name(desc.)</option>
          <option value="4">Duration</option>
        </select>
      </th>
      <th></th>
      <th></th>
      <th></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    @foreach (var upload in Model) {
      <tr>
        <td>@Html.ActionLink(upload.Name, "Edit", "Audio", new { name = upload.Name }, null)</td>
        <td>
          <audio controls controlsList="nodownload" preload="metadata" id="preview-player">
            <source src="~/User_Data/@upload.UserId/@upload.Name" type="audio/mpeg">
            Your browser does not support the audio element.
          </audio>
        </td>
        <td>
          <a href='@Url.Action("Download", "Audio", new {path = upload.Path})'>
            <img src='@Url.Content("~/Content/Images/download.png")' id="download-image" title="Download" />
          </a>
        </td>
        <td>
          <a href='@Url.Action("Delete", "Audio", new {id = upload.Id})'>
            <img src='@Url.Content("~/Content/Images/delete.png")' id="delete-image" title="Delete" />
          </a>
        </td>
      </tr>
    }
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Is it possible for us to see the table HTML?

Comment: @user7290573 I added the table code

Comment: I would suggest taking each duration and converting it to a number of seconds - that way you can use simple numeric sorting. `1:30` would be 90 seconds

Comment: If I use the HTML Audio/Video DOM duration Property it will give me the length in seconds, I don't know how to refer to each specific player in the comparation.

Comment: You can give each `<audio>` element a unique ID, I'm not sure what library you're using to create that foreach-loop in your HTML, but I'm sure that library offers some way to create a unique ID-tag for each iteration of the loop.